# CentOS 7: Unable to complete install: internal error: libxenlight failed to create new domain

Tags: centos, xen, libvirt

I have a problem with the installation XEN on CentOS. I did everything through virt-manager, I did not try through the commands, but there should be the same error as I understand it. Worth the graphics subsystem, LXQT, lightdm, `4.9.127-32.el7.x86_64 GNU/Linux`. 
I get the following error:

> Unable to complete install: 'internal error: libxenlight failed to create new domain 'win7''
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 89, in cb_wrapper
>      callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
>    File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 2553, in _do_async_install
>      guest.start_install(meter=meter)
>    File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 498, in start_install
>       doboot, transient)
>    File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 434, in _create_guest
>      domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)
>    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 3725, in createXML
>      if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self)
>   libvirtError: internal error: libxenlight failed to create new domain 'win7'

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: That’s not a CentOS kernel. What additional repos and software did you install?

Comment: Installed epel-release, centos-release-xen. Updated. I followed this instruction: [link](https://computingforgeeks.com/xen-virtualization-in-linux/). Then I installed the old with `--enablerepo=centos-release-xen-*`. Did not help. I have always tried to create through virt-manager. I just can not find an article where it would normally explain how to create virtual machines in XEN through a terminal. Someone manually writes a config, someone uses virt-install. It is not clear how to correctly. And about the parameters there are ambiguities. Maybe someone knows a really good article or manual?